# Using Capybara and Selenium to hover over an element

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have a link on a page which only appears when hovering over a certain element. But I can't figure out how to emulate this and then click on the link so I can cucumber test it using Capybara and Selenium.

Anyone know how to do this? I've tried executing javascript and and also trying to talk to the selenium driver directly but so far I'm not having much luck...

Answer (score 3):

This question is a few years old, so the answer might have changed. In newer versions of Capybara there are a few different ways to do it, depending on the driver you're using.

For selenium, you can execute javascript:

```
page.execute_script '$("#element").trigger("mouseover")'
```

Newer versions of selenium-webdriver support a hover method:

```
find('#element').hover
```

For capybara-webkit, the driver supports triggering events on the element:

```
find('#element').trigger(:mouseover)
```

I originally found the answer to this question from [here](http://aokolish.me/blog/2012/01/22/testing-hover-events-with-capybara/) and [here](http://qastuffs.blogspot.com/2013/05/capybara-hover-over-element.html).

Comment: the second form (`.hover`) triggers css `:hover` rules, the other two don't seem to (they only trigger javascript handlers of the mouseover event). I use `.hover` e.g. to make invisible links fade in before clicking them.

Answer (score 2):

Use Selenium's `fireEvent` on a `mouseover` event and then pause for your required hover time.

Comment: Hmm... I must be doing something stupid. I've tried the line: page.driver.browser.fireEvent(selector, "mouseover") in my web step but I get the following error: undefined method `fireEvent' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x10501bde0 browser=:firefox> (NoMethodError) any ideas?

Comment: @borrible do you have any example code to do this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on similar one i used following see this might help you.

Using Selenium IDE.
1. Navigate to the required page.
2. Start selenium IDE and Get the Link target.
3. Change the Command to **mouseOver** Double click the the command in Selenium IDE.
4. It will Show the link wchich you needed.
5. Again Start recording and record the required Link.

When you Double click the mouseOver command it creates the simulation of mouse over through IDE and you can Use your mouse to record the popup link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded in getting Capybara + the Selenium driver to "hover" over an element. This is the code I'm using:

```
module Capybara
  module Node
    class Element
      def hover
        @session.driver.browser.action.move_to(self.native).perform
      end
    end
  end
end
```